# What does "git+" mean in the url?

Tags: git

I installed jquery through npm in two apps.
Looking through the `package.json` I see this difference:

`"url": "https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/MIT-LICENSE.txt"`
`"url": "git+https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/MIT-LICENSE.txt"`

What is the difference? What purpose does the `git+` serve.

Comment: One is a URL and one is a GIT-URL https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is said [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) that it serves the purpose of specifying it is a git url and allows you to use a *commit-ish* after a hashtag in the url

> Git URLs as Dependencies
>
> Git urls can be of the form:
>
> git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
>   git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
>   git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
>   git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
>   git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
>
> The commit-ish
>   can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to
>   git checkout. The default is master.

---

A commit-ish is basically an id that git is able to process to target some specific contents (*tag, sha or branch*)

For instance let's say you have a commit which has a commit sha (abbreviated) of abcdef12

You could use it like this

```
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#abcdef12
```